# Using box.net, dropbox, (OR ANY cloud storage) with a C++ application

Tags: c++, api, cloud, dropbox

How do you use cloud storage such as Dropbox in your C++ Apllication ? I've checked out their API and they only have Java, Python, and Ruby options. If you cant use dropbox with a c++ app, is therte any cloud storage provider that has an API for C++.

Comment: On their site they list also a community version for C#. Is that an option?

Comment: This article, [C++ - Bringing RESTful Services to C++ Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Dn342869.aspx) discusses new Microsoft technologies for REST with an example using DropBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drop box APIs seem to be wrappers for a http interface.
So if you want to hit them up from C++ you can use a http supporting library like libcurl to access stuff using the [REST api](http://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs#api-specification)

Comment: I'm using the python API, (since it's possible to embed python in C/C++ Applications); But There seems to be no documentation on how to negin using the dropbox API

Comment: Actually its quite possible to embed into C or C++, a C#, Java, python or objective C interface (and probably the other supported languages too, but I've personally done the 4 I list). However IMO the overhead and plumbing needed to do so are overkill for talking to a REST style interface.

Answer (score 4):

[Droper](http://coinonedge.com/droper/) is an open source C++/Qt Dropbox client that I have recently wrote. It can be compiled for Windows and Linux, but the GUI is optimized for Symbian mobile phones. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've found several differnet APIs on their website, righ under the place you propably found the ruby / pathon stuff..

http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/
http://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet

Not sure if this is, wha you were looking for..

Comment: I've seen them and none of them are for C++. I specifically mentioned C++ for a reason